# Rename command not working when using JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

Trying to rename a file/folder using JSch API executing them as shell commands is not working. `mkdir` and `rmdir` are working fine.

JDK version – 11.
JSch version – 0.1.55.

Using the following code.

```
ChannelExec execChannel = null;
try {
  execChannel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
  execChannel.connect();
  execChannel.setCommand("rename dir1 dir2");
  execChannel.start();
} catch (JSchException ex) {
  throw new IOException(ex);
} finally {
  if (execChannel != null) {
    execChannel.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Update:

- The SFTP server is hosted on a CentOS machine
- `mv`, `ren`, `rename` - None of them worked
- How do we know the command did not work - The folder name is still the old name. Also the `execChannel.getExitStatus()` gives `-1`. No error is thrown

Answer (score 3):

You are most probably executing a wrong command. If you are connecting to Linux, the command to use is [`mv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html).

---

Though, you should not use shell commands for trivial file operations like creating and removing a directory and renaming a file/directory. That's a very fragile approach.

Instead, use the the standard file management API of SSH, the [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) ([`ChannelSftp`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) in JSch).

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
sftpChannel.connect();

sftpChannel.mkdir("/path/dir1")
sftpChannel.rename("/path/dir1", "/path/dir2");
sftpChannel.rmdir("/path/dir2");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jsch I believe that the remote host is a Unix-like system. There is no command `rename` in Unix. Use `mv` instead.